# Is pattern matching by property existence possible in C#?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

Lets say we have this example hierarchy:

```
abstract class Shape { }

class Circle : Shape 
{ 
    public int Radius { get; set; } 
}

class Rectangle : Shape 
{ 
    public int A { get; set; } 
    public int B { get; set; } 
}
```

I am wondering if it's possible to use pattern matching in C# on a variable of type `Shape` to determine if it has property Radius e.g.

```
// Imaginary syntax
if (myShape is { int Radius} )
{
}
```

I have not found that this is possible, so I assume the answer is no, but probably someone knows better.

Alternatives that I can think of:

1. Enumerate all the known scenarios (i.e. of Type Circle, etc.), downside is that an introduction of a new type in the future will break it
2. Introducing an interface, which might be cumbersome depending on the scenario
3. Using reflection (not too nice)

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: @canton7 sad :)